# C language and how to free memory from a 2d character array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

In the code below how I try to free the memory I get the message:
Segmentation fault (core dumped):

```
char *str = "15:14:34:-32:1076:-4177:0";
char *strarr = (char**) malloc((n*sizeof(char*)));
    strcp = strdup(str);

    strspt = strtok(strcp, ":");

    strarr[cont] = strspt;

    while(strspt)
    {
        cont++;
        strspt = strtok(NULL, ":");
        strarr[cont] = strspt;
    }

    strarr[cont] = NULL;
```

When I try to free memory with:

```
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        free(strarr[i]);
    }
```

I get the message:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

You have only allocated dynamic memory for `strarr` and `strcp` (i.e. using `strdup`). So only free them.

Like:

```
free(strcp);    // Free the memory allocated by strdup
free(strarr);   // Free the memory allocated by malloc
```

BTW: Your code doesn't show it bu I assume `cont`is initialized to zero